# HttpURLConnection.getInputStream returning null android

Tags: android

In my application I am trying to download audio file but using HttpUrlConnection 's getInputStream() method but getInputStream() method returning null.I don't have any idea why it is happening.Any help?Below is the code I am using

```
URL downloadURL = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    File file = null;
    try {
        downloadURL = new URL("http://thelearningapps.com/admin/userfiles/Rhymes/Arabic/The_Wheels_On_The_Bus_Arabic.mp3");
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            //return;
        inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        file = AppUtility.getInternalDirectoryForRhymes(this, rhymeName);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read = -1;
        long totalRead =0 ;
        int totalLength = httpURLConnection.getContentLength();
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        RhymesActivity.getInstance().registerMyReceiver();
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            totalRead += read;
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
            sendMyBroadCast(totalRead, totalLength, rhymeName);
            if (progressbarDetails != null) {
                progressbarDetails.isDownloading = true;
                progressbarDetails.rhymeName = rhymeName;
            }
        }
```

I am using above URL in browser it is streaming fine but in application it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If that is your actual code then you have a simple error:

```
    if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        //return;
    inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
```

your `if` is causing inputStream to not being assigned, or beeing assigned only on error.

Comment: Oh my god!! What a silly mistake I have made ..Thank you  very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot calling `httpURLConnection.connect()` before using `httpURLConnection.getInputStream()` (and `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()`).

Comment: Is it necessary to call connect()?Because I am not calling it in my code it is working fine?What is actually the impact of not calling this connect() method?

Comment: If it works without, it is probably handled automatically, and you should not worry about it

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to checking if the response code is ok not the negative

Comment: yes I was testing the same as you mentioned as @luskan mentioned is right